# How to extract URL from html source with sed/awk or cut?

Tags: sed, awk

I am writing a script that will download an html page source as a file and then read the file and extract a specific URL that is located after a specific code. (it only has 1 occurrence)

Here is a sample that I need matched:

```
<img id="sample-image" class="photo" src="http://xxxx.com/some/ic/pic_1asda963_16x9.jpg"
```

The code preceding the URL will always be the same so I need to extract the part between:

```
<img id="sample-image" class="photo" src="
```

and the `"` after the URL.

I tried something with sed like this:

```
sed -n '\<img\ id=\"sample-image\"\ class=\"photo\"\ src=\",\"/p' test.txt
```

But it does not work. I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You can use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) like this :

```
grep -oP '<img\s+id="sample-image"\s+class="photo"\s+src="\K[^"]+' test.txt
```

or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -r 's/<img\s+id="sample-image"\s+class="photo"\s+src="([^"]+)"/\1/' test.txt
```

or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F'src="' -F'"' '/<img\s+id="sample-image"/{print $6}' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. I really needed something that matches the ID too, because there are other images on the file and using just the src would not work, you rock!

Comment: Yes, I guessed that, and other answerers seems not. Feel free to accept/upvote my answer if it fits your needs.

Comment: Really appreciate the awk example here. It nailed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `GNU` grep then you can do something like:

```
grep -oP "(?<=src=\")[^\"]+(?=\")" test.txt
```

If you wish to use `awk` then the following would work:

```
awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed as

```
echo $string | sed 's/\<img.*src="\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things about the `sed` command you are using:

```
sed -n '\<img\ id=\"sample-image\"\ class=\"photo\"\ src=\",\"/p' test.txt
```

- You don't need to escape the `<`, `"` or space. The single quotes prevents the shell from doing word splitting and other stuff on your `sed` expression.
- You are essentially doing this `sed -n '/pattern/p' test.txt` (except you seemed to be missing the opening backslash) which says "match this pattern, then print the line which contain the match", you are not really extracting the URL.
- This is minor, but you don't need to match `class="photo"` since the `id` already makes the HTML element unique (no two elements share the same id w/in the same HTML).

Here's what I would do

```
sed -n 's/.*<img id="sample-image".*src="\([^"]+\)".*/\1/p' test.txt
```

- The `p` flag tells `sed` to print the line where substitution (`s`) was performed.
- `\(pattern\)` captures a subexpression which can be accessed via `\1`, `\2`, etc. on the right side of `s///`
- The `.*` at the start of regex is in case there is something else preceding the `<img>` element on the line (you did mention you are parsing a HTML file)